# Mime type error when Importing CSS in Stackblitz

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I would include material design in my Angular project. I'm using Stackblitz online IDE.

The problem is when I include css file I get this error

```
The stylesheet was not loaded because its MIME type, ”text/html“ is not ”text/css"
```

Here's my code in index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.min.css">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<link "href=node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head> 
<my-app>loading</my-app>
```

and styles.css :

```
body {
background:#e8e8e8;
font-family: 'Muli';
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in your html. The `href` tag is inside your path.

Change the link to :

```
<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css">
```

Comment: if you follow this guide, the usage is same as I mentioned: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming.md

Comment: share your stackblitz link

Comment: adding `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";` to my styles.css file solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You got a typo in
`<link "href=node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">`
Must be
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css">`

Comment: Did you tried adding `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"` in your stylesheet as mentioned by the https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming.md